# Query component returning null for data BUT network shows a response

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

Data is null, BUT, I see the response in both /grahpql & network.

WHAT THE QUERY IS: BAREBONES:

```
query GetProductById($product_id: Int!) {
  getProductById(product_id: $product_id) {
    id
    product_id
    name
    product_type
    create_time
    update_time
    sizes
    click_url
    price
    discount_price
    coupon_code
    sale_date
    sku
    colors
    in_stock

    regions {
       ...domestic
       ...international
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: UPDATE: NARROWED IT DOWN TO THIS:::

```
    regions {
     ...domestic
     ...international
    }
```

I THINK THIS IS THE ISSUE.. NO?

```
import { IntrospectionFragmentMatcher } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  introspectionQueryResultData: {
    __schema: {
      types: [
        {
          kind: 'INTERFACE',
          name: 'Regions',
          possibleTypes: [
            {
              name: 'domestic'
            },
            {
              name: 'international'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
 export default fragmentMatcher;




  import fragmentMatcher from './RegionFragmentMatcher';

  const cache = new InMemoryCache();
  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    fragmentMatcher,
    cache,
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `${config.url}/graphql`,
      credentials: 'include'
    }),
     resolvers: Resolvers(cache),
     addTypename: true,
     dataIdFromObject,
     introspection: true
    });

    export default apolloClient;
```

Comment: What's the query?

Comment: Updatd to include query

Comment: ok, I started pairing back some of the query keys and at some point, it worked. SO, there seems to be something that is bunking it up. BUT WHY in one case it works, another it doesn't....? very weird. So, I removed about half of the query keys... I will put it back and go one by one..

Comment: Please see my latest comment, perhaps you can help me.

Comment: Is there any warning or error shown in the console?

Comment: invariant.esm.js:34 You are using the simple (heuristic) fragment matcher, but your queries contain union or interface types. Apollo Client will not be able to accurately map fragments. To make this error go away, use the `IntrospectionFragmentMatcher` as described in the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments.html#fragment-matcher AND.. this:
invariant.esm.js:34 WARNING: heuristic fragment matching going on!  ----- BUT, I am using one.

Comment: ALSO, I ended up removing on the fragments from "regions" and it worked.. SO, yeah, I think how I am using FragmentMatcher.. you see anything that sticks out?

Comment: Are you exporting the `fragmentMatcher` variable as the default export? I don't see that shown in the code you pasted.

Comment: Yes. I forget to cut/paste, but its there. I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FragmentMatcher should be passed to the InMemoryCache constructor, not the ApolloClient constructor:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink(),
});
```

Comment: BINGO!!! thanks bro!! That was it.. I don't know how I missed that. I just assumed it was something way more involved.. lol. Again, thanks!!!!!